# Include files inside modules folder in Prestashop

Tags: php, include-path, prestashop-1.6

I have created a subfolder inside my store in Prestashop inside the **/classes/** subdirectory with the name **service** (e.g **/classes/service/**).

I'm trying to include the php file of a module that I have created myself to access to its methods with the following line of code inside a class that I have created inside **/classes/service/** :

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../modules/mymodulename/mymodulename.php')';

class A {    
      .
      .
      .

      public function callmodule(){
           $obj = new MyModuleName();
           $obj->someMethod();
      }

}
```

I use it in the include the `/../../` to go two directories up, one to get out to  the **service** folder and another one to get out to the **root** folder of the store, but the problem is that the above line is not returning anything when I call it, only gave me a blank page without errors or warning and if I delete it's works fine, but I need to access to this file.

There is a better way to access to the file without errors ?

**PD** : When I mean call the class **A** it's because I put a rule inside my *.htaccess* to redirect a specific call to some class like a dispatcher where the **A** class its called.

Comment: use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/modules/mymodulename/mymodulename.php'`

Comment: Also, make sure that there's nothing in mymodulename.php that isn't causing a fatal error. THe fact that you say nothing is returned makes me think you're seeing a blank page.  Check your error logs if you have access to them.